# Desktop Manager performance

Tags: display, display-manager

I was using GNOME at 15.10, yesterday i got some issues and upgraded the ubuntu to 16.04. I am using LightDM right now but starting or launching some programs seems so slow. Firstly 16.04 seems slower, is that normal? Secondly are there any performance differences between GDM and LightDM?
For both cases, how can i make my pc faster?

Comment: Well, yes. You said it yourself: LDM is faster. Please [edit] your question and clarify what kind of difference you are asking about.

Comment: @terdon edited, i hope you can understand my question with that version.

Comment: You seem to be asking 3 separate things: i) is there any performance difference between GDM and LDM (yes, there is; as you saw, LDM is faster). ii) Is 16.04 slower than 15.10 (not answerable, depends on how you've set things up) iii) "How can I make my PC faster" again, not really answerable. You need to give us more details about your set up, hardware, desktop environment etc. More importantly, you seem to be confusing the login manager (GDM, LDM) with the desktop environment (Gnome, LXDE, Unity, etc). Your login manager won't affect your choice of environment nor the speed of your machine.